# Can't call didSelectRowAtIndexPath from tableView embedded inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, touch

I have two tableViews and I need to show all the content of the first one then the hole content of the second one, some times these two tableviews are longer than the view that's why I need to embed the two tableViews in a UIScrollView, but the problem is that I can't call the tableview:didselectrowatindexpath method, Could anybody help me on how to active touch in the tableView?

Comment: normally you don´t need to do anything to enable the touch ability except NOT disabled it. Some code would be helpful to understand your problem better. AND maybe you should move away from two tableviews since I don´t think, that is the best approach, maybe you should have a look at what `sections` in tableviews are and use multiple sections instead of two seperate views.

Comment: did you set yourself as the tableView's delegate and dataSource? also, as Ckouta points out, it's strange having two tableViews in one controller - normally you would use a TableViewController with two sections.